# Error:415 HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, web-services, httpurlconnection

I want to connect to a `web-service` and send a big file, i use `HttpURLConnection` like this:

```
 private void doFileUpload() {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 8 * 1024 * 1024;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream;
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(getRealPathFromURI(fileUri)));

            URL url = new URL("https://url.com/service.asmx?op=Method");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", SOAP_ACTION);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "url.com");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/>"
                    + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("<soap:Body>" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("<IncluirMultimedia xmlns=/" + "www.url.es/>/" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("<identificadorGUID>" + Guid + "<" + "/identificadorGUID>" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("<numeroServicio>" + codigoServicio + "<" + "/numeroServicio>" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("<contenido>" + ficheroAEnviar + "<" + "/contenido>" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("<tipoMultimedia>" + "0" + "<" + "/tipoMultimedia>" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("<coordenadaLatitud>" + "0.0" + "<" + "/coordenadaLatitud>" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("<coordenadaLongitud>" + "0.0" + "<" + "/coordenadaLongitud>" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("<extension>" + "mp4" + "<" + "/extension>" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("<cuando>" + "0" + "<" + "/cuando>" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("<IncluirMultimedia>" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("</soap:Body>" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("</soap:Envelope>");
            buffer = new byte[8192];
            bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
            fileInputStream.close();

            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            conn.getContentLength();
            if (conn.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
                inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            }
            else {
                inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getErrorStream());
            }
            inStream.close();

        }
        catch (IOException ioex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
    }
```

And my `soap-request` must be:

```
POST /url/url.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: url.es
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "www.url.com/IncluirMultimedia"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <IncluirMultimedia xmlns="www.url.es">
      <identificadorGUID>string</identificadorGUID>
      <numeroServicio>string</numeroServicio>
      <contenido>base64Binary</contenido>
      <tipoMultimedia>int</tipoMultimedia>
      <coordenadaLatitud>string</coordenadaLatitud>
      <coordenadaLongitud>string</coordenadaLongitud>
      <extension>string</extension>
      <cuando>int</cuando>
    </IncluirMultimedia>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I cant use `ksoap2` because i need to send a very large file and this causes `OutOfMemoryError`. That's why i need to use this class.

I'm getting `error 415`, what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: how about looking here for code 415: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E415.html

Comment: Type not allowed, but i set             conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
 but in conn.getcontenttype return me null..

Comment: did you manage to do this successfully? I have the exact service that you have.

Comment: where is the file your trying to send what is its size.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
 conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

You are sending xml, I guess the server expects it.